# Inserting specific text from a text file into JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a text file ( output.txt) which contains the longitude and the latitude for id's ranging from 2001 - 2013. The lat , long and the corresponding ID is in the same line as shown below:

116.078063888889 -33.8620819444444 2001

116.075777777778 -33.8738927777778 2002

116.061067777778 -33.8625277777778 2003     etc.....

Goal: insert the lat and long numbers from 2001 in the text file into  the JavaScript variables in Mapbox.html so that the location marker has the right co-ordinates.  Thank you so much for your time!!.

Mapbox.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>

    body{
background-color: rgb(12, 11, 11);
overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    #map{

        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        right:0;
      
    }

    
</style>

    
<body>
    
<div id='map' style='width: 112.75vw; height: 163.5vh; ' ></div>
<script>


// TO MAKE THE MAP APPEAR YOU MUST
// ADD YOUR ACCESS TOKEN FROM
// https://account.mapbox.com
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZJ4cW8xcnRja2tqdiJ9.7z7Eyrj3iexJ9uDVYIT0yw';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // stylesheet location

   center: [115.83333, -32.01667], // starting position [lng, lat]
    zoom: 11// starting zoom
    
  
});
var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({color:"#ff3300",dragable:true,scale:0.8}).setLngLat([115.83333, -32.01667]).addTo(map)



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume the text file (`output.txt`) is being served from the same spot at your front end app? If so then conceptually what you want to do is:

1. Fetch the text file
2. Parse it by row
3. Locate the rows you need, and get the lat/long values

```js
const NEWLINE = '\n';
const SEPERATOR = ' ';

function parseOutputTextIntoRows(text) {
  return text.split(NEWLINE);
}

function findLatLong(rows = [], id) {
  const foundRow = rows.find((row) => row.split(SEPERATOR)[2] === id);
  const latLongStrings = foundRow.split(SEPERATOR).slice(0, 1);
  return latLongStrings.map((str) => Number(str));
}

fetch('output.txt')
  .then((response) => parseOutputTextIntoRows(response))
  .then((rows) => findLatLong(rows, '2001'))
  .then(([lat, long]) => { /* do something with lat and long */ });
```

Comment: Hey Luke Thanks!! But which variables has the lat and long?

Comment: @jo8080 The ones called `lat` and `long` inside the "do something" function.